# How can override bootstrap classes with withStyles in material UI

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, material-ui, react-bootstrap, react-with-styles

I want to override some of bootstrap classes.Currently I'm using withStyles of material UI in this I can write css in Js format for my own classes.But I want to override bootstrap classes of some buttons, container etc...In material UI it will generate class names dynamically. I can do with scss but I'm using theme changer in my application.

I except the overriding of bootstrap classes by using withStyles of material UI.

Comment: What have you tried? Please create a Minimal, reproducable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/leh8e in this demo they are used css in js. In the same way I want to override bootstrap classes.

Comment: Then try to do it and show some non working code..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Bootstrap Classes with HTML Tag and write CSS for the HTML Tag. Example

```
 <div className="customButtonWrapper">        //JSX file
   <BootstrapButton></BootstrapButton>
 </div>


.customButtonWrapper {                         //CSS file
   >button {
    background-color: red !important
  }
 }
```

Comment: I can override in css but I want css in Js. https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/ in this demo they are using styling in Js. In the same way how can I override bootstrap or any other 3rd party plugins in Js.

Comment: Yeah..Use styled-components mpm package. You can pass props to the CSS Components. So you can achieve whatever you want.

Comment: We can try below way to override global styles.https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css

Answer (score 0):

By using global styles of css in js we can override the styles of any third party library.

Please refer below link for overriding the global styles

https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal in js:

```
<span className={`mt text_bold ${classes.loginTitle }`}>Login to Synapse</span>
```